# fetchBatchSize and cache in NSFetchedResultsController ignored

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using an NSFetchedResultsController to display messages in a chat room app.

The context variable is assigned in appDelegate and a reference to that context used in the chat room.

```
let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
```

I initialize the NSFRC as follows in viewDidLoad:

```
func initializeResultsController() {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Message>(entityName: "Message")
    let messageSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateCreated", ascending: true)

    request.sortDescriptors = [messageSort]
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "chatRoomId == %@", self.chatRoomId)
    request.fetchBatchSize = 30

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "messageDateSectionIdentifier", cacheName: self.chatRoomId)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
    }
}
```

The sectionNameKeyPath ("messageDateSectionIdentifier") is a derived property so that the sections can be divided into calendar days.

I have two problems.  Firstly the batchSize seems to be ignored and secondly the cache seems to make no difference to the performance.  The more messages the longer the delay when selecting the chat room.  about 1 second for 1500 messages.

When I edit scheme to show coreData info in console, the batch request for 30 rows is performed multiple times when the view first appears and in one case the array size is 1500.  Not sure whether that is the fault array or the populated array.  The console printOut is:

```
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0013s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0014s for 1454 rows.
CoreData: annotation: Bound intarray _Z_intarray0
CoreData: annotation: Bound intarray values.
```

And this is repeated after this multiple times with value of 30 rows.

I have tried simplifying the sectionNameKeyPath to just dateCreated to see if the derived sections were the problem but there was no difference at all.  I should also mention that as with all chat apps, the app initially scrolls to the bottom when it is presented.

What I want is for the cache to work and also for the fetchBatchSize to work so that only 30 rows are fetched from coreData initially until the user starts to scroll up.  The delay now caused by this method is having a measurable impact on my app performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the cause of the problem in my case.

If you are referencing the fetchedResultsController in tableView heightForRowAt then the fetchBatchSize will loop through and load all data in loops of the fetchBatchSize you specify.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let item = self.fetchedResultsController!.object(at: indexPath)

    // get and return height of item
    return item.heightOfItem
}
```

If you use UITableViewAutomaticDimension or define a height that doesn't require a reference to fetchedResultsController (i.e. a fixed height) then you won't have this problem and fetchBatchSize will work as it should.

Unfortunately I found UITableViewAutomaticDimension not acceptable for scrolling performance so I guess I have to manually configure batch loads using offsets.

I also had one additional issue that was causing the loop loads of data.  That was the sectionNameKeyPath was in my case a transient property.  This also caused problems but unfortunately is necessary.

If you are having problems with fetchBatchSize with an NSFetchedResultsController I would advise looking at these two issues.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that `batchSize` is not respected by a `fetchedResultsController`. A NSFetchedResultsController does a fetch and then tracks all changes in the context to see if anything is added, removed, moved or changed.  If it only fetched a subset of the matching entities by respecting batchSize it would be unable to do it's job.

You can get around this by setting a predicate to only fetch message after a certain date.  In order to figure out what is the cutoff date you can do a single fetch first, where batchSize = 1 and the batchOffset = [how many message you want initially in you fetchedResultsController]. As more message come in the collection will increase in size beyond your initial limit.

Also be aware that the sectionNameKeyPath is called for EVERY element in the collection.  So doing even a small amount of work there can cause huge delays.  Don't create a calendar or a dataFormatter in then sectionNameKeyPath - reuse a single one.

Comment: That’s great to know. I thought the nsfrc may track only the changes on the results array. Thx also for advice on calendar. Will definitely change that to reuse one instance.

Comment: The fetchedResultsController tracks all changes that match the predicate.

Comment: Makes sense. I’ll try the predicate method you suggested. Thx.

Comment: if I want to reuse a calendar in the extension of  @objc public var messageDateSectionIdentifier: String? {... would it be best to create that in the appDelegate and refer to the appDelegate instance in the extension above?

Comment: there are a large number of tutorials that show the nsfetchedresultscontroller working fine with a fetchBatchCount.  may need to revisit this

Comment: I would love to have a sample of core which shows a fetchedResultsController respecting batchSize.  I have never seen it.  I've seen a lot of tutorials that have it. I never seen it effect behavior.